# How to test onload using jest and testing library during fireEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a function like this to check the image and returns a Promise

```
export default function checkAspectRatio(value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(value);
    reader.onload = function(value) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = value.target.result;
      img.onload = function() {
        const aspectRatio = this.width / this.height;
        resolve(aspectRatio);
      };
    };
  });
}
```

and call it inside the onChange of input type="file"

```
//..
Object.defineProperty(file, 'aspectRatio', {
  value: await checkAspectRatio(file)
});
//..
```

However, by using the test below it seems that the Promise is not resolved inside the onload function and resulting in error in the test because it cannot find the text in the document

```
it('should choose file and validate the file', async () => {
    //...
    const inputFile = getByLabelText('input-button-upload');
    const mockImage = new File(['png'], 'test.png', {
      type: 'image/png',
    });
    fireEvent.change(inputFile, {
        target: {
        files: [mockImage]
        }
    });
    expect(await inputFile.files[0]).toBe(mockImage);
    expect(getByText('test.png')).toBeInTheDocument();
}
```

How can I properly test this?

Comment: What's `file`? Show the code